# Why does "docker attach" hang?

Tags: linux, docker, freeze

I can run an `ubuntu` container successfully:

```
# docker run -it -d ubuntu
3aef6e642327ce7d19c7381eb145f3ad10291f1f2393af16a6327ee78d7c60bb
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3aef6e642327        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            condescending_sammet
```

But executing `docker attach` hangs:

```
# docker attach 3aef6e642327
```

Until I press any key, such as `Enter`:

```
# docker attach 3aef6e642327
root@3aef6e642327:/#
root@3aef6e642327:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Why does `docker attach` hang?

**Update**:

After reading the comments, I think I get the answers:

prerequisite:

**"docker attach" reuse the same tty, not open new tty.**

(1) Executing the `docker run` without daemon mode:

```
# docker run -it ubuntu
root@eb3c9d86d7a2:/#
```

Everything is OK, then run `ls` command:

```
root@eb3c9d86d7a2:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@eb3c9d86d7a2:/#
```

(2) Run `docker run` in daemon mode:

```
# docker run -it -d ubuntu
91262536f7c9a3060641448120bda7af5ca812b0beb8f3c9fe72811a61db07fc
```

Actually, **the following should have been outputted to stdout from the running container:**

```
root@91262536f7c9:/#
```

So executing `docker attach` seems to hang, but actually it is waiting for your input:

```
# docker attach 91262536f7c9
ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@91262536f7c9:/#
```

Comment: You do not run a container with your command, as there is no CMD or ENTRYPOINT in the associated Dockerfile, try running a wordpress or nginx container, from the dockerhub http://registry.hub.docker.com

Comment: @user2915097: Sorry, I don't understand your comment relates with the question. Could you elaborate it? Thx!

Comment: Try `docker run -p 80:80 nginx`

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile. Do you have a RUN and ENTRYPOINT directive in it?

Comment: There are several people who have opened issues on the docker Github repo to address this, see docker response here [docker attach container hangs, requires input](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10094) and here [docker attach hangs setting terminal state when attaching to container](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8521)

Comment: First of all the command `# docker run -it -d ubuntu` contradicts itself. `-it` means "runs it interactively with a tty", while `-d` means "runs it in background".

> The docker attach command allows you to control it interactively

[See the doc.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)

Comment: @Auzias: If I run `docker run -d ubuntu` without adding `-it`, the docker will not be Up state.

Comment: Indeed, "the docker will not be Up state" because you do not provide any command, then the `bash` is run, but as there is no tty nor `stdin` nor `stdout` then `bash` exits. If you run for instance `docker run -d ubuntu nc -l 1445` then the container will stay up.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It does not really *hang*. As you can see in the comment below (You are running "`/bin/bash`" as command) it seems to be expected behaviour when attaching.

If instead of `enter` you would start typing a command, you would not see the *extra* empty prompt line. If you were to run

```
$ docker exec -it ubuntu <container-ID-or-name> bash
```

where `<container-ID-or-name>` is the ID or name of the container after you run `docker run -it -d ubuntu` (so 3aef6e642327 or condescending_sammet in your question) it would run a *new* command, thus not having this "stdout problem" of attaching to an existing one.

As far as I understand you attach to the running shell and just the stdin/stdout/stderr - depending on the options you pass along with the run command - will just show you whatever goes in/out ***from that moment***. (Someone with a bit more in-depth knowledge hopefuly can explain this on a higher level).

As I wrote in my comment on your question, there are several people who have opened an issue on the docker github repo describing similar behaviour:

- [docker attach [container] hangs, requires input #8521](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8521)
- [docker attach hangs setting terminal state when attaching to container](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10094)

> > Since you mention shell, I assume you have a shell already running. attach doesn't start a new process, so what is the expected behavior of connecting to the in/out/err streams of a running process?
> > I didn't think about this. Of course this is the expected behavior of attaching to a running shell, but is it desirable?

> Would it be at all possible to flush stdout/stderr on docker attach thereby forcing the shell prompt to be printed or is it a bit more complex than that? That's what I personally would "expect" when attaching to an already running shell.

> Feel free to close this issue if necessary, I just felt the need to document this and get some feedback.

- Taken from a [comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8521#issuecomment-59942873) on this [github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8521). You can find more insight in the comments of this issue.

Comment: Could you check my update is right or not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For me the very last "ls" has the prompt reprinted as soon as I start typing, but other than that it looks good.

Comment: `docker exec -t -i [container] /bin/bash` is what go me on the terminal I needed to browse the container's file system.

Comment: @FrancescodeGuytenaere, I believe you need to change: 
$ docker exec -it ubuntu bash <container-ID-or-name>
to
$ docker exec -it ubuntu <container-ID-or-name> bash

Answer (score 50):

I ran into this issue as well when attempting to attach to a container that was developed by someone else and already running a daemon. (In this case, it was LinuxServer's `transmission` docker image).

#### Problem:

What happened was the terminal appeared to 'hang', where typing anything didn't help and wouldn't show up. Only `Ctrl-C` would kick me back out.

`docker run`, `docker start`, `docker attach` all was not successful, turns out the command I needed (after the container has been started with `run` or `start`) was to execute `bash`, as chances are the container you pulled from doesn't have bash already running.

#### Solution:

`docker exec -it <container-id> bash`

(you can find the `container-id` from running `docker ps -a`).

This will pull you into the instance with a functional bash as `root` (assuming there was no other explicit set up done by the image you pulled).

I know the accepted answer has captured this as well, but decided to post another one that is a little more terse and obvious, as the solution didn't pop out for me when I was reading it.

Comment: The accepted answer probably does have useful info, but it buries the lead. Thanks for getting to the point.

Comment: In my particular situation, I replaced bash with sh, so my command looks like this: docker exec -it <container's ID> sh
You can also use container's name instead of container's ID.

Answer (score 7):

When I run `docker attach container-name`, then nothing output, even `Ctrl-c` is invalid. So, first try

```
docker attach container-name --sig-proxy=false
```

and then `ctrl-c` can stop it. Why it didn't output anything?
just because the container doesn't output. Actually I need to enter my container and run some shell command. So the correct command is

```
docker exec -ti container-name bash
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19797086)

Comment: Sorry, I just described my case.

Comment: I assume you mean `-it` rather than `-ti`.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once for the following reason:

It could be that the bash command inside the container is executing a "cat" command.

So when you attach to the container (the bash command) you are actualy inside the cat command which is expecting input. (text and/or ctrl-d to write the file)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access command line, just make sure you run your container with `-i` flag at start.

Answer (score 0):

### I just had a similar problem today and was able to fix it:

Here is what was happening for me:

```
docker-compose logs -f nginx
Attaching to laradock_nginx_1
```

Then it would hang there until I quit via CTRL-C: `^CERROR: Aborting.`

`docker ps -a` showed that what SHOULD have been called `laradock_nginx` did not exist with that Image Name, so I figured I'd just remove and re "up" that container:

```
docker stop cce0c32f7556
docker rm cce0c32f7556
docker-compose up -d laradock_nginx
```

Unfortunately: `ERROR: No such service: laradock_nginx`

So I did a `sudo reboot` and then `docker ps -a`, but `laradock_nginx` still wasn't there.

Luckily, `docker-compose up -d nginx` then worked and  `docker-compose logs -f nginx` now works.

Answer (score 0):

Using: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID/NAME bash`

Instead: `docker attach...`