# Why "docker attach" not working and blocking my konsole on ubuntu

Tags: docker

basically, I have a running container I would like to attach console on it.
I have used `docker run -p 8080:80 test` to start my container. It seems to be working fine.

my docker ps looks like this :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
81b27e2525f1        test            "/bin/sh -c /start.sh"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   vigilant_bassi
```

Then tried to attach my a console

```
user@user:~$ docker attach 81b27e2525f1 
    ls  
    ^C
    
    
    
    ls
    ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^C^C^C^C^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

This is not working and I am unable to detach.
Then I thought it was a bug I tried to open on new and I had the exact same issue. Now I have multiple consoles blocked.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35573698/6608257), it is not the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

ps my docker version is : `Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3`

Comment: I have this problem on a Discourse image, ever found out what it was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try instead a [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), for debugging purpose:

```
docker exec -it test bash
```

(assuming your test image has a `bash` installed, or at least an `sh`. If based on Alpine, an `ash`)

[`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) uses the container’s stdio/stderr, so you need to makle sure your script is actually flushing/printing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the output of your container without attaching to it:

```
docker logs -f <container-id>
```

But if you really need to attach to it you have to start it with the -it flags:

```
docker run --detach -it -p 8080:80 test
```

To attach:

```
docker attach <container-id>
```

Don't use Ctrl+C to detach because that will be a signal that will quit program. Use Ctrl+P then Ctrl+Q to detach.