# Having difficulties to attach an up state container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-container

I have created a docker container which is up and running in the background. I tried to attach the container in my terminal using the container id. It enters the container but I can't do anything in it. So, I have to exit every time using ctrl+c.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "docker attach" hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573698/why-does-docker-attach-hang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the comment by *Lawrence Cherone* did not help you consider the following options:

1. If you want to invoke a command in a already running container, use `docker exec`.
   You can *exec* into you container by it's **name** or **id**. This means you can run a command in a running container. See [docs.docker.com: docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

   Example: 
   The docker exec command runs the command `bash` in a running container.

   ```sh
   docker exec -it <container-id> bash
   ```

   *Note*: This will really invoke a new command and do not attach to the currelty running command.
2. If you just want to get the putput of a container, you can use `docker logs`. Again you use your container name or id.
   See [docs.docker.com: docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

   Example:

   ```sh
   docker logs <container-id>
   ```